# Jetty 404 Problem accessing /. Reason: Not Found

Tags: java, jetty

I'm trying to get started with Jetty but only getting 404 not found at localhost.com:8080/api, /api and /api/example.

This is my main method:

```
Server server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/example");
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
config.packages("api");
config.register(new CORSConfig());

ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));
handler.addServlet(holder, "/api/*");

try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
} finally {
        server.stop();
        server.destroy();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a `Server`, and then a `ServletContextHandler` then doesn't attach them together.

Before `server.start();`

call `server.setHandler(handler);`